# Is there a way to read Raw midi data in java?

Tags: java, javax.sound.midi

Using `javax.sound.midi` i've managed to open my midi device up for outputting a `.midi` file in the past but the issue is i need to be able to pickup the midievent in it's raw form as in `"3C40"/"903C40"`.

I'm able to find documentation on opening transmitters/receivers/sequencers but no code examples using these to output to say a string as the raw data from the midi device example of which is my yamaha ypt-240
digital keyboard.

Basically the reasoning behind why i want this raw data is to make some simple keybindings that would be triggered by said raw data from the midi device almost like a stream deck or using software that allows this.
The ShortMessage seems like the way to go but again can't find any code using it the way i would like to.

Every example is mididevice||file.midi -> synth||mididevice
I need a way to intercept that input java is getting from the device...

please help lol

Comment: Sorry about that :o

Comment: Java has a pretty good tutorial on its MIDI system. It explains all classes in detail. If that is not enough I would recommend reading the MIDI specification itself and how it works. You will need it anyways if you plan to work with the raw data. Here is the [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/overview-MIDI.html).

Comment: So using Sequencer I could probably do a temporary .midi file and read the single ShortMessage, SysexMessage, or MetaMessage contained within this .midi.     Possibly use this in a switch with VK outputs